# Extract all words from fields of objects inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have this array:

```
array = [{"full_name":"louis jackson","title1":"english teacher,"description":"good and nice teacher"},{"full_name":"peter carey","title1":"math teacher,"description":"bad and ugly teacher"}]
```

i need to get this array

```
results = ["louis","jackson","english", "teacher",good","and","nice","teacher","peter","carey","math","teacher","bad","and","ugly","teacher"]
```

i have tried:

```
results = [];
array.forEach(item => {
results.push (item.full_name.split(" "));
results.push (item.title1.split(" "));
results.push (item.description.split(" "));    
}
```

i just get multiple separated arrays;  can anyone guide me in right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is close, but you just have to `concat` the arrays instead of pushing the split arrays into `results`. Like this:

```js
let array = [{"full_name":"louis jackson","title1":"english teacher","description":"good and nice teacher"},{"full_name":"peter carey","title1":"math teacher","description":"bad and ugly teacher"}]
let results = [];
array.forEach(item => {
  results = results.concat(item.full_name.split(" "))
      .concat(item.title1.split(" "))
      .concat(item.description.split(" "));    
});
console.log(results);
```

Here's another take using `for..of` and `for..in` so you don't need to manually define the property names:

```js
let array = [{"full_name":"louis jackson","title1":"english teacher","description":"good and nice teacher"},{"full_name":"peter carey","title1":"math teacher","description":"bad and ugly teacher"}]
let results = [];
for(const item of array)
  for(const prop in item)
    results.push(...item[prop].split(" "))
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a bit of clean code to do it all for you

```js
array = [{"full_name":"louis jackson","title1":"english teacher","description":"good and nice teacher"},{"full_name":"peter carey","title1":"math teacher","description":"bad and ugly teacher"}]

var results = array.flatMap(obj => {
  const vals = Object.values(obj);
  return vals.flatMap(val => val.split(' '));
})

console.log(results);
```

`Object.values` just gets the value from each property of each object, so you're not dealing with the keys like 'full_name' or 'title1'

Then once you have the values, you split them by the space and return them as an array.

`flatMap` makes sure that if you return an array of arrays, it flattens it 1 layer.

edit -- here's it as a one liner:

```
var results = array.flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj).flatMap(val => val.split(' ')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are always strings and probably the words could be separated by multiple spaces:

This `v.split(/ +/)` splits each phrase as an array of strings which will be concatenated to the main array (the accumulator in the `reduce` function).

```js
let array = [{"full_name":"louis jackson","title1":"english teacher","description":"good and nice teacher"},{"full_name":"peter carey","title1":"math teacher","description":"bad and ugly teacher"}];
let result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  Object.values(c).forEach(v => a = a.concat(v.split(/ +/)));
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

result is an empty array. The `split()` method returns an array. When you call `push()` on an array, you're adding an array to an array. Every time you call push, you add another array to the array. So you have an array of arrays. What you want is a single array with all the values.

So call `split()` on each value to get an array, iterate through the values, then call `push()` on the values of the array, not the array itself.

Try this

```
var results = [];
array.forEach(item => {
   var names = item.full_name.split(" ");
   names.forEach(i => result.push(i));

   var titles = item.title1.split(" ");
   titles.forEach(t => result.push(t));

}
```

You can take @Klaycon advice and use

`.concat()` instead of `forEach` loop.
If you're not using an older version of IE you can use `...` a[ssign operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: Avoid just dumping code; it's always better to accompany an answer with an explanation.

Comment: `titles.forEach(t => result.push(t));` can be done much easier with `result.push(...titles)` or `result = result.concat(titles)`